# How to use a c-style struct in multiple classes

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

I want to use a c-style struct in several classes but I am struggling with its (global) access.

I define the struct in the header file of class “Utilities”:

```
typedef struct
{
    int        length;
    SInt16     *someData;
} NewStruct;


+ (NewStruct *)initStructWithValue:(int)length;
```

In another class I initialize this struct with the class method of Utitlities:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NewStruct  *newStruct;

_newStruct = [Utilities initStructWithValue: 5]
```

Now I want to use newStruct in other classes. However, when I put

```
extern NewStruct *newStruct;
```

at the top of the header-files it doesn’t work, it seems that I don't have access to newStruct.

I get the error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What am I doing wrong and what would be the best way to do it? Or might it be better to avoid using this struct as global variable?

Comment: Why do you use a c struct instead of an objetive c class?

Comment: I use it in combination with core audio with very low-latency requirements

Comment: @ganchito55 even apple uses them, see `CGRect`,`CGPoint`. They are useful for some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extern` keyword means "declare without defining". In other words, it is a way to explicitly declare a variable, or to force a declaration without a definition. But when the linker assembles your object code it needs the variable the be defined somewhere, which means you have to have a source where the variable is there without the extern keyword `NewStruct *newStruct;`.

With the method above, you are considering this variable as a global singleton. If you need multiple instances, you should just use the `@property` as you specified above.

Comment: This is what I currently implemented. However, with this code I do not seem to get access to myNewStruct in other classes (currently, it is initialized as the local variable _myNewStruct). Apparently, it is not correct to write “extern NewStruct *myNewStruct;” in the header file of other classes? Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. I update the answer.